# How are futures and speculations evaluated differently?

Tags: programming-languages, parallel-programming

In *[Practical Foundation of Programming Languages](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/pfpl/)*

> **38 Futures and Speculations**
>
> A future is a computation that is performed before it is value is
> needed. Like a suspension, a future represents a value that is to be
> determined later. Unlike a suspension, **a future is always evaluated,
> regardless of whether its value is required**. In a sequential
> setting, futures are of little interest; a future of type τ is just an
> expression of type τ. In a parallel setting, however, futures are of
> interest because they provide a means of initiating a parallel
> computation whose result is not needed until later, by which time it
> will have been completed.
>
> **A speculation is a delayed computation whose result might be needed for the overall computation to ﬁnish.** The dynamics for speculations
> executes suspended computations in parallel with the main thread of
> computation, **without regard to whether the value of the speculation
> is needed by the main thread**. If the value of the speculation is
> needed, then such a dynamics pays off, but if not, the effort to
> compute it is wasted.
>
> Futures are work efﬁcient in that **the overall work done by a
> computation involving futures is no more than the work done by a
> sequential execution.** Speculations, in contrast, are work inefﬁcient
> in that **speculative execution might be in vain—the overall
> computation may involve more steps than the work needed to compute the
> result.** For this reason, speculation is a risky strategy for
> exploiting parallelism. It can make use of available resources, but
> perhaps only at the expense of doing more work than necessary!
>
> **38.3 Parallel Dynamics**
>
> Futures are only interesting insofar as they admit a parallel dynamics
> that allows the computation of the future to go ahead concurrently
> with some other computation. In this section, we give a parallel
> dynamics of futures and speculation in which the creation, execution,
> and synchronization of tasks is made explicit. **The parallel dynamics
> of futures and speculations is identical, except for the termination
> condition.** Whereas **futures require that all tasks are completed
> before termination**, **speculations may be abandoned before they are
> completed**.

Both futures and speculations are evaluated, regarless of whether their values are needed.
So how are futures more efficient than speculations?

What does it mean by "futures require that all tasks are completed before termination, speculations may be abandoned before they are completed"?

I still don't understand how futures and speculations  are evaluated differently.

Thanks.

Comment: These terms are not universally used with those specific meanings. The terminology might be in part specific to the book you're reading. When you come across a term like *promise* or *future* in an API or document, you should read its specific definitions. Evaluation mechanics also differ drastically between languages, e.g. Rust futures don't make progress unless they are awaited/polled but JavaScript promises are fire and forget, and can be used for background IO tasks.

Answer (score 2):

They're actually evaluated the same.

The key is to ignore whatever it is the *language* or the *library* you're using calls it and concentrate on the *design* of the software firing off the parallel operations, and the *intent* of the programmer thereby.

If you *know* you're going to use the result of the computation in the *future* and you want to have it ready when you eventually need it and you've got the processors to run the computation on, so your goal is to reduce latency, then it is a *future*.  You're definitely going to use the result so the CPU cycles aren't going to be wasted, that is, there's no better use to put them to then to calculate something you *need*.

But maybe you don't absolutely *need* the result in the future but you think under some circumstances (depending on what might happen in the next few cycles...) you *might* need it - and if you *do* need it you're going to want it right away (to reduce latency when and *if* you need the result).   Then it is a *speculation* - you're anticipating a possible advantage - and if it turns out you *do* need the result well and good, but if it happens that you don't need it after all then those CPU cycles were wasted and you might have been able to use them for something else if you had predicted the future better, or if you had had computations you positively needed to perform that you had to delay (and got later) because a processor was busy on your speculative work.

In practice concurrent libraries may or may not let you *cancel* an in-progress computation anyway.  Frequently you can't because the underlying mechanism - maybe a (userspace) thread - can't actually be cancelled.  (Because it is in general unsafe to simply stop a userspace thread and delete its resources - it might be holding a lock or some kernel thing that then would never be closed/freed.) So you might find that libraries that call their constructs `futures` (with corresponding `promises`) don't have any ability to cancel and you either have to `join` with all your futures or access all your promises before you can exit.  And in libraries like that - you may very well want to speculate and fire off computations before you need them in the hope of needing them - but choose well and try not to do it too much - unless you're swimming in processors ...

Answer (score 2):

A speculation isn't a very common term from a programmer's point of view, but my understanding is they are evaluated identically to a future. The difference is in what you do with the result.

To restate in more familiar terms, what they call a "future" appears to be like an `async` function that is always `await`ed. A "speculation" is like an `async` function that you start in case its result will be useful, but you don't have the information yet to know if you want to `await` it or not. If you decide not to `await` it, the cpu time you spent running it ends up getting wasted.